# TFS Continuous Developement major project update

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS Continuous Development model
Main Trunk
-> Various Development branches 
-> Various Release branches

All merging back to main trunk

**Now we need some major changes to our folder structure and solutions**

How do you handle folder restructure in above model of TFS usage?

- do i need to draw line and create new structure from latest Main trunk and lock all branches and do updates then creates branches with restructured new trunk.
- Or am i underestimating TFS, would be able to handle major folder structure updates and propagate over to branches. As long as i know if we move around folders in branch or trunk it don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS *can* handle this, and does it by "renaming" each file by changing it's TFS location path.

I've been able to do this in a child branch, merging it up into the trunk, and then back into another branch.

It does get a little tricky, and you are sometimes presented with confusing dialog boxes because it can't automatically resolve renaming changes.

When I got this box, I resolved any actual content changes in files. I was then able to cancel out of manually resolving every renaming change without any problems, and everything worked perfectly.